# Why would the Android app Release Version ask for addTestDevice with admob?

Tags: android, admob

I am not able to get the real ads even when I install my app from Play Store. Its requesting to addTestDevice (which I am not doing in production build)  How do I test real ads?

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in the [Admob FAQ section](https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/9092685?#ts=9092687%2C9092741);

> If you just created your Ad Unit ID recently, sometimes you will have to give some time before the ad unit is is activated.

When did you create your Ad Unit IDs?